# Giving access on google cloud storage to users outside Google Apps domain

Tags: g-suite, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

## Scenario:

1. Registered domain *xyz.com* with *Google Apps for Business*
2. Created user *infra@xyz.com*, using which created a project on *Google Cloud Platform*
3. Created a bucket on *Google Cloud Storage*
4. Under bucket on *Google Cloud Platform Console*, in ***Edit Bucket Permissions*** added following 3 users under ***Name***, with ***Entity = User*** & ***Access = Writer***

   - *user1@xyz.com* (user created in the same *Google Apps for Business*)
   - *user2@gmail.com* (user created on *Gmail*)
   - *user3@abc.com* (user created on different *Google Apps for Business*)
5. Users try to access the bucket using https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/xyz-com/?project=xyz-com

## Issue:

*user1@xyz.com* was able to get the bucket listing, but it failed for *user2@gmail.com* & *user3@abc.com*. Which means any user outside *Google Apps for Business* is unable to access the bucket in-spite of giving explicit bucket permission.

Though I read and tried for a day, could not find any solution for the issue. Please help

Comment: What did Google Support say about this?

Comment: I don't have paid support (am on bronze). I guess this is the only place I can grab their attention to the issue. But if there is a better place please advice

Comment: How is user2@gmail.com authenticating? Are they trying manually via gsutil or the cloud console?

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough, Assuming the project name as _xyz-com_, users try to authenticate & browse the bucket using the URL [https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/xyz-com/?project=xyz-com](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/xyz-com/?project=xyz-com). But they get `You don't have permission to see the storage section`

Comment: Try removing the "?project=xyz-com" part.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, it worked, seems silly of google to have that mentioned in the URL and silly of me to not try that out earlier. Humble request to mention it in answer, so that others do not get lost like me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Brandan Yarbrough, for the suggestion, which worked.

*user1@xyz.com* was able to access the bucket using the URL https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/xyz-com/?project=xyz-com as it had rights to the Google Cloud Platform project *xyz-com*, while other users could not access it for they did not have right to the project.Thus removing *?project=xyz-com* did the trick for those users.

**Conclusion:** always use the URL `https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/<bucket name>/` (without `?project=<project name>`) to access the bucket